# Decimal place not displaying correctly in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, floating-point, decimal

I got the decimal working now but for some reason its displaying backwards. It's probably my lack of math skills but here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender {
    currentNumber = (float)[sender tag] + currentNumber /10;
    priceOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",currentNumber];
}
```

Now when I type on my custom keyboard in this order: 5-2-1, it displays the number backwards: 1.25. I want it to display 5.21. Any ideas?

Comment: Second try? You mean you have asked this before? If you are deleting questions to ask them again, please don't do that again. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74459/user-systematically-deleting-and-re-posting-questions/

Comment: It's not the same question, I just meant second try asking about this particular topic.

Comment: mkay. I've removed the first sentence to prevent any further confusion. :)

Comment: How will the user enter a number like 52.36? Is a number like 52.369 valid?

Answer (score 1):

In your @interface add a new instance variable

```
float currentMultiplier;
```

Set it in your (re-)initialisation routine, so:

```
currentMultiplier = 1.0;
```

and recode the routine you mention in the question as:

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender
{
  currentNumber += (float)[sender tag]*currentMultiplier;
  currentMultiplier *= 0.1;
  priceOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",currentNumber];
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this using an NSString instead of a float?

Comment: Yes; do you want to change your question to ask for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender {

    currentNumber = currentNumber*10 + (float)[sender tag];

    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f",currentNumber];

}
```